# Использование структуры из другого пакета в методе

Tags: golang

Всем привет. У меня есть несколько пакетов в проекте

Пакет models содержит

```
type User_JSON struct {
    UID   string `json:"id"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
    Dob   string `json:"dob"`
}
```

Пакет db содержит

```
func New_user(user models.User_JSON) (bool, models.User_JSON) {
    defer tools.Panic_recover("inserting user in db")
    id, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(user.UID), 2)
    tools.Errors("bcryprgenerate(generating uid)", err)
    user.UID = string(id)
    conn := Connect(tools.Home() + ".conn_config.yaml")
    tx := conn.Table("users").Create(&user)
    return tx.Error == nil, user
}
```

Мне нужно для обьекта User_JSON реализовать метод New()

Я перехожу в третий пакет(api) и делаю там

```
func NewUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    user := models.User_JSON{
        UID:   "123",
        Name:  "testname",
        Email: "test@email",
        Dob:   "22-03-1990",
    }
    user.New() //и, соответственно здесь тоже ругается
}

func (user models.User_JSON) New() { //здесь ругается на user (invalid receiver models.User_JSON (type not defined in this package))
    db.New_user(user)
}
```

Мне, конечно, хотелось бы оставить метод New()в models но тогда cicle import
Я нагуглил что нельзя делать методы для структур находящихся в других пакетах. А как же тогда быть, если я не могу делать метод в пакете со структурой так как это 100% приведет к cicle import, не хочу плодить в разных пакетах одну и ту же структуру(User_JSON)

Comment: Странно добавлять в структуру метод который ее сохранит в бд. Почему в хендлере просто нельзя то же самое вызвать: `db.save(user)`?

Comment: @u_mulder это чтобы найчиться такие методы создавать и использовать. В изначальном варианте я так и делаю, как вы говоритте

Comment: Какие __такие__? Которые вызывают циклическую зависимость?

Comment: @u_mulder вопрос как раз в том, как сделать так чтобы остался метод но не было зависимости

Comment: А от чего там зависимость? И где-то люди умные уже писали - если в пакетах циклическая зависимость, значит пакеты спроектированы __неправильно__.

Comment: Объявите метод `New` для структуры `User_JSON` в том же пакете, где и сама структура. По хорошему, это будет конструктор данной структуры и должен располагаться прям под ней в том же файле.

Comment: @u_mulder согласен, поэтому и переношу. ТАм зависимость будет если в models добавить функцию, которая обращается в пакет с работой с бд, так как в пакете с бд идет обращение к структурам которве в models. По идее методу который обращается в бд не место в models, поэтому и пытаюсь его перенсти и натыкаюсь на проблему, что он должен быть в файле со структурой иначе метод не сделать

Comment: @Borislav буду пробовать

Comment: Это ошибка проектирования. Модель не должна ничего делать с базой данных. Модель хранит данные в памяти в том виде, как это удобно программе. Все операции с базой должен выполнять контроллер. Поэтому метод `New` для типа `User_JSON` должен всего лишь инициализировать поля структуры. В таком случае не будет циклической зависимости.

Comment: "Модель не должна ничего делать с базой данных" Любители Active Record напряглись)

Answer (score 0):

У вас конфликтует имя типа и имя переменной с этим же типом (тип не имеет метода New). Например, назовите переменную user_

Answer (score 0):

Вас могут выручить интерфейсы. Ваш model/User_JSON не должен зависеть от db напрямую. Ему подойдёт любая штука, которая умеет `New_user(user User_JSON) (bool, models.User_JSON)`. Интерфейс надо объявить в том же пакете, который его использует (а не в том, который его реализует). После этого ваш пакет model не будет зависеть от пакета db.

Небольшой пример

```
package foo

type A struct {
        Name string
}

type bInterface interface {
    B(a A) string
}

func (a A) CallB(b bInterface) string {
    return b.B(a)
}
```

```
package bar

import "so/goImportCycle/foo"

type B struct {}

func (b B) B(a foo.A) string {
    return a.Name
}
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "so/goImportCycle/foo"
    "so/goImportCycle/bar"
)

func main() {
    a := foo.A{"Foo"}
    b := bar.B{}
    fmt.Println(a.CallB(b))
    
}
```